# How to know if the user first time enter my site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on some smartbanner. I want them to show if the person is entering the website first time. If they've already visited I don't want to show the smartbanner. Is there any plugin to know that?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: First you need to define "visitor" and "first time."  Conditionally showing output is the easy part, and that can come later.  How do you currently identify your visitors?  Do they log in or authenticate in any way?  If you don't currently identify them, how do you want to identify them?  By a login?  By a cookie in the browser?  By client IP address?  Some other means?

Answer (score 2):

Set a cookie on the client and read the cookie. Or store the `IP` address in your database.

Both are unreliable though.

Comment: combination of both might be the best way. However IP Address changes every 24 hours for most of the users.